# Typescript: Why Omit makes some properties optional?

Tags: typescript, types

```
interface Options {
  [K: string]: any
}

interface UnitOptions {
  name: string
  iswait: true
}

type T1 = Options & UnitOptions

// ! No error without "name" property
const t1: Omit<T1, 'iswait'> = {}
```

I want to use a type of object with any type of values, but with two required fields ("name" and "iswait"). Then in some cases, I want to use this type without the "iswait" field. But after applying `Omit`, the "name" field becomes optional too. How is that?

Comment: [Cannot find name `WmOptions`.](https://tsplay.dev/wEV1VN)

Answer (score 0):

There's no error because the `[K: string]: any` part (called [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)) says that "this object can have any property of any value".

If you add index signature to a interface:

```
{ [K: string]: any } & { name: string }
```

… this now means "this object has property `name` of type `string`, *and any other property of any value*".